# Aptitude validate installed package against deb/repo

Tags: debian, unix, apt, deb, validation

I am bouncing back from disk corruption caused by power failure. All configs and non-repository files are backed up, and I have a list of installed packages, so I can start fresh *this time* but I am looking for a better way, in case next time I can't afford that much down time.

I know apt keeps debs of installed packages laying around. When upgrading sometimes apt asks if I want to keep my config or use the new one, so apt knows the difference between config and binary, and what has been modified since installation (hash?).

Does anyone know how to check installed binaries against the deb for consistency without spending disk writes on extracting the deb? A solution that works for one given package could be adapted to loop across an `apt-mark` list of installed packages, and failed packages get fed to `apt install --reinstall`; I just need the validation logic.

I am using apt 1.4.9 with dpkg-deb 1.18.25. Though I don't think other details should matter too much, I'm running raspian on armhf (raspberry pi zero w).

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it. `dpkg -V`, which uses the stored md5sum. Filter out the ones with a c flag because they're configs. This is what I've got:

`sudo dpkg -V | egrep --color=auto '^.{9}   ' | rev | cut -d\  -f 1 | rev | xargs dpkg-query -S | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u > corrupted_packages.txt`

Once that finishes, I plan to do something like `sudo xargs apt install --reinstall <corrupted_packages.txt`